# How can I add a Facebook share button using the Facebook Javascript SDK in an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using the following code within an Ajax call in Rails:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','#share_button', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: '<%= fb_data[:name] %>',
        link: '<%= fb_data[:link]%>',
        picture: '<%= fb_data[:picture] %>',
        caption: '<%= fb_data[:caption] %>',
        description: '<%= fb_data[:description] %>'
      }
    ); 
    });
</script>
```

This code works fine in html views, but not with a view rendered with ajax. I suspect that this is an issue with when the $(document) and ajax is rendered, but I am not familiar with javascript or ajax to solve this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#share_button').click(function() {
     FB.ui({
       method: 'feed',
       name: '<%= fb_data[:name] %>',
       link: '<%= fb_data[:link]%>',
       picture: '<%= fb_data[:picture] %>',
       caption: '<%= fb_data[:caption] %>',
       description: '<%= fb_data[:description] %>'
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

Does it work ?